# Every infinite subset of E in R having a limit point in E implies E is closed and bounded

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

> Every infinite subset of E in R having a limit point in E implies E is closed and bounded.

Could you please help with a formal proof of this result ?

Comment: $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I dont think the conclusion holds.

Comment: Hint: Assume for a contradiction that $E$ is not closed. Then there exists an infinite sequence of points in $E$ such that... (fill in the blank here)? Now assume for a contradiction that $E$ is not bounded. Then there exists an infinite sequence of points in $E$ such that... (fill in the blank here)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $E$ was not closed, $\mathbb{R} \setminus E$ would not be open, that is, there would be a $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus E$ such that every open sphere centered in $x$ intersects $E$. Thus $x$ would be the limit of an infinite sequence of $E$ that lies outside of $E$, contradiction.

If $E$ was not bounded, then by the very definition you could then construct a sequence having no limit, thus an infinite subset having no limit point.

Comment: Thank you very much! it's elegant and very well proven!

Comment: May you clarify more why that infinite sequence (in your first paragraph) has no limit point in $E$ other than $x$?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what is written in Walter Rudin chapter 2, Theorem 2.41. The proof for closeness is given as follow.

If $E$ is not closed, then there is a point $\mathbf{x}_o \in \mathbb{R}^k$ which is a limit point of $E$ but not a point of $E$. For $n = 1,2,3 \dots $ there are points $\mathbf{x}_n \in E$ such that $|\mathbf{x}_n-\mathbf{x}_o| < \frac{1}{n}$. Let $S$ be the set of these points $\mathbf{x}_n$. Then $S$ is infinite (otherwise $|\mathbf{x}_n-\mathbf{x}_o|$ would have a constant positive value, for infinitely many $n$), $S$ has  $\mathbf{x}_o$ as a limit point, and $S$ has no other limit point in $\mathbb{R}^k$. For if $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^k, \mathbf{y} \neq \mathbf{x}_o$, then
\begin{align}
|\mathbf{x}_n-\mathbf{y}| \geq &|\mathbf{x}_o-\mathbf{y}| - |\mathbf{x}_n-\mathbf{x}_o|\\
\geq & |\mathbf{x}_o-\mathbf{y}| - \dfrac{1}{n} \geq \dfrac{1}{2}|\mathbf{x}_o-\mathbf{y}| 
\end{align}
for all but finitely many $n$. This shows that $\mathbf{y}$ is not a limit point of $S$, see also Theorem 2.20 of Walter Rudin.

Comment: I was stuck in understanding why $S$ is infinite. Also I need clarification why the last two inequalities hold. May you help, please?

Answer (score 0):

First assume that E is not bounded. Then, we can inductively construct a sequence
{$x_j$ } . where j ∈ N ⊂ $R^n$ such that ∥$x_j$ ∥ > ∥$x_j − 1$∥ + 1. Such a sequence cannot have a limit point (why?).
Next, assume E is not closed. Let z ∈ E Closure \ E .
There is a subsequence of distinct points {$x_j$ },j ∈N ⊂ E
such that ∥$z − x_j$ ∥ < 1/ j . Thus, S = {x j : j ∈ N} is an infinite subset of E . For any y ∈$ R^n$ such that y $\neq$ z,
we have that
∥$x_j − y$∥ ≥ ∥$y − x_0$∥ − ∥$x_j − x_0$∥ ≥ ∥$y − x_0$∥ − $\frac{1}
{j} > 
\frac{1}{2}$ ∥$y − x_0$∥
for sufficiently large j.
Thus, y is not a limit point of S and the only limit point of S is not in E .