# Prove that a set E in R^n is closed and bounded if and only if every infinite subset of E has a point of accumulation that belongs to E

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Prove that a set $E \subset R^n$ is closed and bounded if and only if every infinite subset of $E$ has a point of accumulation (aka limit point) that belongs to E

Hi all,

Working on an exercise from Thomson, Bruckner & Bruckner's Elementary Real Analysis and been stuck on this one for quite some time. Here is what I have so far.

$\Leftarrow $ 
Suppose every infinite subset $E_k$ of $E$ has a point of accumulation that belongs to $E$. 
We wish to show that $E$ is closed and bounded.

First, suppose that $E$ is not closed. 
Then for all limit points, $x_0$ of $E_k$, $x_0 \in E_k \land x_0 \notin E$. 
But by assumption, every infinite subset $E_k \subset E$ contains a point of accumulation of $E$, so this is a contradiction. 
Therefore $E$ is closed.

$\Rightarrow$
Now, suppose $E$ is not bounded. . .

It's this right implication that I am stuck on. I can't find any justification for the argument that I want to make, which is that if any infinite subset of E contains limit points of E, then E must be bounded. This is based off the second argument from this question's top answer, from Chocosup. [Every infinite subset of E in R having a limit point in E implies E is closed and bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962311/every-infinite-subset-of-e-in-r-having-a-limit-point-in-e-implies-e-is-closed-an)

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: This proposition holds for arbitrary metric spaces: $(X, d)$ is sequentially compact if and only if every infinite subset of $X$ has an accumulation point. The proof is not difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $E$ is unbounded, for each $k \in \mathbb N$ choose $a_k \in E$ with $\|a_k\| \ge k$. Then $A:=\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}$ has no accumulation point.

---

Suppose $a \in R^n$.  I claim that $B_1(a) \cap A$ is finite, so $a$ is not an accumulation point of $A$.  Let $L = \|a\|$.  Note if $k \ge L+2$ then $\|a_k\| \ge k \ge L+2$ and so by the triangle inequality $\|a_k-a\| \ge L+2-L > 1$, so
$a_k \notin B_1(a)$.

Notation $B_r(a) = \{x \in R^n : \|a-x\| < r\}$.

Comment: So sorry for the simplistic question, I've struggled with these concepts a lot and trying to now remedy missing intuition. Could you explain a little more about why, as a consequence of the norm being greater than k, ${a_1, a_2, . . .}$ has no accumulation point?

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick responses and further explanation. I really appreciate it!